# Hypernym for "restaurant", "cafe" and other food places

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms, food

I am looking for a hypernym for all places that provide food, beverages, or both, of any quality or price — such as *restaurant, cafe, fast-food* and so on.

Comment: Some common informal and slangy terms are "eatery", "beanery", and just a few from M-W.com online: cafeteria, lunch counter, luncheonette, lunchroom, snack bar; greasy spoon, hash house; chophouse, steak house; pizzeria; coffeehouse, coffee shop, estaminet, teahouse, tearoom, tea shop [chiefly British]; bar, barroom, inn, tavern. But you can look these up yourself at Dictionary.com. They have a wonderful thesaurus.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The name of the industry in the US  is “food service” (or “foodservice”); according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foodservice) the corresponding term in BE is “catering industry”. Within the industry, individual outlets are “food service operations”.

In ordinary speech the most ‘generic’ term is “restaurant”, which embraces both ‘sit-down’ (table service) establishments and fast-food outlets, but tends to exclude institutional operations such as hospital or corporate cafeterias. “Eatery” is sometimes used, but it’s old-fashioned and implies a down-scale establishment; referring to a Michelin-starred restaurant as an “eatery” would be distinctly jocular.

Travel guides, newspapers and the like will often use verbal headings: “Eating”, “Eating Out”, “Dining Out”, and so forth.

EDIT:
tchrist asks for a term embracing hot-dog stands and the like. Within the industry they're still “food service operations”; they may be grouped with outlets like Burger King as “quickservice operations”. In ordinary conversation—well, they’re not “restaurants”. They *are* “eateries”, but as I said that’s not a term used much any more. I don’t think there’s any generic term embracing everything from the hot-dog stand to Maxim’s. If I had to find an X to plug into “What sort of X do you want to have lunch at?” I’d have to resort to ‘place’ or something equally vague.

Comment: What would you call a hot-dog stand, or a roving falafel cart?

Comment: @tchrist see my edit

Comment: Outside the US I think a restaurant implies sit-down, table service.  When McDonalds call themselves a restaurant it sounds like they're having a laugh.

Answer (score 3):

In law the category is often referred to as a ["retail food establishment"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22retail%20food%20establishment%22), as opposed to a wholesaler or caterer. Hot dog stands and Michelin-rated restaurants are both included.

Answer (score -1):

The most suitable hypernym for all places that provide food, beverages, or both, regardless of quality or price, is "foodservice establishment." It is a general term that encompasses all types of foodservice businesses, including restaurants, cafes, fast-food chains, food trucks, bars, pubs, and other similar establishments that serve food and drinks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How exactly is this different, and why is it better than what appears in the answers posted earlier? While new answers to old questions are welcome on this site, they are expected to make it clear that they are genuine additions to what already appears on the same page.