# 'Horeca', the commercial sector around selling food and beverages: is it English? Alternatives?

Tags: nouns, terminology, abbreviations, translation, is-it-a-word

In Dutch there's a quite commonly used word that denotes the commercial sector around selling food and beverages for immediate (or near-immediate, e.g. take-out meals) consumption: *horeca*. (This usually also includes snackbars and the like, but not supermarkets)

I'm in the process of creating an English version of a website that has it as a menu item, and I'm looking for a translation of approximately similar size (i.e. not a full sentence). I found that the word horeca also exists in English, but the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horeca) is quite small and seems to be written by a Dutch native. The definition given is the exact definition of the word I'm looking for, but I'd rather have something that's less obscurely used in English..

> **Horeca** (or HORECA) is the sector of the food service industry that
>   consists of establishments which prepare and serve food and beverages.
>   The term is a syllabic abbreviation of the words
>   Hotel/Restaurant/Café.

I'm edging towards distrusting the fact that it's a word that English natives would understand. Does anyone have any alternatives with a simialr meaning?

Comment: Hotel restaurants and cafes fall in the category of *restaurants* in English. So why can't you just use the word *restaurant*? (Or maybe [*restaurants and bars*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=restaurants+and+bars%2C+bars+and+restaurants&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).)

Comment: Catering industry would probably be the English equivalent.

Comment: You first say "the entirety of the commercial sector around food and beverages", but then you say "Hotel/Restaurant/Cafe" which is only a single sector of the food service industry. The entirety of the commercial food/beverage sector includes food and beverage production, processing, distribution, and in general a lot more than what you list as *Horeca*. You should clarify which part you really mean.

Comment: @spiceyokooko Catering is not right; restaurants and cafes where you "eat in" are not doing catering.

Comment: @Mark Beadles You're correct, that was way too broad and only caused confusion. I ment the latter. It's just about the last part of the chain, where people buy food/drinks for immediate or near-immediate consumption. Edited the Q.

Comment: @spiceyokooko On further research, I see that in UK "catering industry" does include any place where food is prepared outside the home; in the US the term is not used the same.

Comment: @MarkBeadles As you've realised *catering* is a generic term used in the UK for the food and drink industry and includes wholesale, production, distribution and end sales. e2a I see where the confusion came from, my use of the word *English*. You darned Americans make life very complicated for us Brits :)

Comment: It is not the culture in English to make abbreviations using initial syllables. The English culture is limited to first letters. The only situation that is similar (that I can think of now) is geographical: Tribeca for "Triangle below Canal Street", in NYC, SoCal for southern California.

Comment: Possibly helpful (and possibly a duplicate): [hypernym-for-restaurant-cafe-and-other-food-places](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90809/hypernym-for-restaurant-cafe-and-other-food-places)

Comment: Just to be complete and answer the OPs title question, no, the word 'horeca' is not standard English (it may be used in specific circles but I am not aware of them).

Comment: What is the audience for this website?  Audience would be a primary factor in any choice of name.

Comment: The references to hotels in this question, and in the *ho* of the term itself, are confusing. Hotels may have or not have restaurants, but their defining characteristic is that they provide overnight accommodations for travellers. Does the concept of horeca include all that, or are hotels mentioned here only because of their restaurants? If the latter, then it is not necessary to mention them separately, because hotel restaurants are already covered by the concept of a restaurant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The US National Restaurant Association calls this the [restaurant industry](http://www.restaurant.org/aboutus/). More generally, the USDA calls the sector [foodservice outlets](http://www.ers.usda.gov/topics/food-markets-prices/food-service-industry.aspx):

> Foodservice outlets are facilities that serve meals and snacks for
>   immediate consumption on site (food away from home).

I do not know the corresponding UK or AUS terms, if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: That would be acceptable in British English, also.

Answer (score 1):

The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horeca) provided by the OP states:

> The Dutch Uniforme Voorwaarden **Horeca** (UVH) is translated into English as Uniform Conditions for the **Hotel and Catering Industry**.

An (informal) alternative in [eateries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/eatery) might also serve:

> a restaurant or cafe. (BrE)
>
> a restaurant or other place where people can be served food. (AE)

Answer (score 0):

Horeca is used in Belgium, the Netherlands, Luxembourg and Switzerland in the different languages spoken in those countries. That a single word is used for economic activity in hotels, restaurants and cafés reflects local ideas that the three are closely related and should for example be addressed by the same economic policies.

In the UK, *catering* and *hospitality* have some overlap with the term but are not exact equivalents and they too represent local ideas on the grouping together of sectors, which are not the same as those on the continent.

While European integration has encouraged some convergence in terms of nomenclature and conceptual framework, the political systems of Member States remain separate and largely retain their own distinct terms and concepts, which are the product of their individual historical experiences.

When translating horeca into English it is therefore best to either a) say you what you mean i.e. economic activity based around hotels, restaurants and/or cafés or b) use a near equivalent that your audience would understand, provided that generalisations are appropriate for the context.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the WSET Level 4 Diploma course in Wines.

In this context HoReCa is used as a term to cover the Hotel, Restaurant, Catering/Cafes. It seems to be a relatively well defined term in the industry.  Likely of US origin but now widely used to describe a specific sector of the industry that sells products (in this case wine) as opposed to retail (supermarkets, specialist wine shops etc).

Seems to have been useful enough as a term or category to leach into other lanquages.

I would not have been familiar with the term before studying the wine / retail industry so suspect that this term is not widely in use in the population and only likely to be used by people interested in studying the food/drinks industry

Comment: [WSET = Wine & Spirit Education Trust.]