# A word or phrase to refer to restaurant sector?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, expression-choice

It's my first time here. In Spanish, we have the word "restauración" to refer to the restoration of paintings, for example, and to places where food is served.
For the first meaning, I believe the translation into English would be "restoration," but I think it doesn't fit the second meaning.

What would be the correct term to refer to the industrial sector encompassing restaurants, bars, cafeterias, taverns, etc.?

Comment: I stand to be proven wrong, but I don't think that there is one. The problem is "restaurant" - this sector is divided into "dining/fine dining" "pub/bar food" and "fast food" and also may include meals "to go". You should give a reasonable sentence to illustrate the context in which you intend to use this word/phrase.

Comment: @Greybeard This is just: the restaurant business or industry, as an economic category of business.//We would not say industrial sector here.

Comment: Miguel, _restauración_ only refers to _restaurants_ in Spanish (see the RAE definition [here](https://dle.rae.es/restauraci%C3%B3n)). However, your question asks for a word that also covers bars and cafeterias, neither of which necessarily has food. Note that there is no direct equivalent to the Spanish "bar" or "cerveseria" which does "platos combinados" etc. in English. In the UK, specifically, you do have pubs which are usually expected to serve food as well, but the word _bar_ suggests a place that most likely doesn't provide food. Can you clarify what you need?

Comment: @terdon Cafeterias don't necessarily have food? That is exactly what they have: food. A bar in Spanish is basically a bar in English. And cafeteria in **Spanish** is a café or bar where food is sometimes served.

Comment: Miguel Murcia, what is the important part of your question? Are you looking for the correct English translation of the word restauración, or are you looking for an English word that refers to the industrial sector encompassing restaurants, bars, cafeterias, taverns, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Horeca', the commercial sector around selling food and beverages: is it English? Alternatives?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96033/horeca-the-commercial-sector-around-selling-food-and-beverages-is-it-english)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, the answers to that question can function as answers to this one, but the **questions themselves** are not the same. One would need, at least, to change the title of the other one for this to be its duplicate. A somewhat better in its current form, but still not perfect, basis for declaring this question to be a duplicate is [Hypernym for "restaurant", "cafe" and other food places](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90809).

Comment: @jsw29 The CV-reason is 'Does this answer your question?' not 'Is this question absolutely identical to yours?'

Answer (score 10):

The term encompassing  restaurants, bars, cafeterias, taverns, etc. is "the hospitality sector" or "hospitality industry". This is using the [second definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hospitality) for the word *hospitality* listed in the Merriam-Webster dictionary:

> the activity or business of providing services to guests in hotels, restaurants, bars, etc. —usually used before another noun
>
> > a hospitality suite
> >
> > Valet parking may be the most commonplace, least understood corner of the hospitality industry.
> > —Bruce Feiler
> >
> > … has turned the hospitality business upside down with his far-out hotel designs … —Robert Herzbrun

Note that this is still not a direct translation of the Spanish *restauración* since *hospitality industry* encompasses all aspects of hospitality and recreation, including for example travel. So airlines might be categorized as part of the hospitality industry, specifically in the "travel and tourism" sub-section.

So if you want to refer to those businesses providing food and drink and no other forms of hospitality, excluding hotels, for instance, then you would talk about the "food and beverage" or "food and drink" sectors instead.

Comment: No, hospitality is everything together.  Here the term would be: the restaurant business or industry.

Comment: @Lambie which is precisely what I explain in the answer. Please at least read the whole thing before commenting. Even better, don't comment at all. If you disagree, downvote, and if you have a better suggestion, post an answer. Note, however, that _restaurant industry_ would exclude bars, cafeterias and anything else not explicitly a restaurant. Hence my choice of _food and drink_.

Comment: The OP does not properly define the Spanish word. But it's in the Spanish dictionary: Real Academia Española.

Comment: the hospitality industry in Spanish is industria de la hospitalidad, not restauración. So your upvotes are mistaken.

Comment: @Lambie: I've upvoted this answer purely to spite you in the face of your arrogant claim that you know better than others how they should have voted on this. Furthermore, you're on a crusade of being right that's unrelated to the actual goal of both the question being asked and the answer. Pedantry is not helpful when it creates problems instead of answering them.

Comment: @Flater Never arrogance, only what I actually know. From 35+ years in the translation/interpretation business (from Spanish, French and Portuguese to English). It always amazes me how people who are not translators react angrily when they miss the boat.

Comment: No boat was missed though. Its pretty clear that no such clear boat exists and alternatives that might still fit the bill were given. What is your problem ? Your last statement insinuates that only translators get things right ?

Comment: @leoOrion The issue here **is translation**. So, the answer is yes to your question *in this specific case*.

Comment: Hospitality is too broad, it includes not only restaurants and bars, but also hotels, convention halls, and other businesses which provide guest services.

Comment: @barbecue is this not adequately explained in the answer? Did you read the last two paragraphs? I thought I explain that clearly.

Comment: @terdon Your answer includes two different answers, one being hospitality, the other being food and beverage. I have no problem with the second answer, just the first.

Comment: @barbecue Hospitality is the same word in Spanish. Restauración is not food and beverage. food and beverage [industry] is alimentación y bebidas. or de alimentos y bebidas.

Comment: @Lambie I am going by the OP, who asked "What would be the correct term to refer to the industrial sector encompassing restaurants, bars, cafeterias, taverns, etc.?"  Hospitality is too broad to be a good answer for that question. Food and beverage is much closer.

Comment: @barbecue The OP's **main question** is about restauracíon, which he mistakenly believes means:  restaurants, bars, cafeterias, taverns, etc. **in Spanish**. And in any case, food and beverage is completely different as I just showed above. And for these we don't say: industrial sector.

Comment: @lambie we disagree about what the main question is that OP asked. I believe the main question was "What would be the correct term to refer to the industrial sector encompassing restaurants, bars, cafeterias, taverns, etc.?"

Comment: @barbecue it is one answer, explaining the usage of the term _hospitality_ and then, since that is not limited to eateries, suggesting ways of limiting it. Since the question, however, explicitly mentioned "bars" and the OP hasn't clarified if they mean that in the way it is used in Spain—which includes places we would likely call "cafés" or just "restaurants", that offer food—or in the way it is usually used in English, to describe an establishment that sells alcohol and little else, I figured I should offer both choices.

Comment: @barbecue For me, the main question was the Spanish word restauración, the definition of which, the OP gets wrong in English, and presumably thus in Spanish. I have updated my answer to cover most possibilities.

Comment: @terdon Many restaurants also have bars, and many bars do serve food, so I don't think the distinction is that important. If we want to get super-pedantic we can break out the ISIC and NAICS industrial classification systems.

Comment: Frankly, I would prefer to drop it. You have been perfectly civil, @barbecue, but continuing here risks forcing me to interact with Lambie again and I really don't want to do that. All of these questions, after all, can only be answered by the OP.

Comment: @terdon I understand completely.

Answer (score 9):

This is the *foodservice* industry. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foodservice):

> The **foodservice** (US English) or **catering** (British English) industry includes the businesses, institutions, and companies which prepare meals outside the home. It includes restaurants, grocery stores, school and hospital cafeterias, catering operations, and many other formats.

Comment: How is this different from my answer?

Comment: I missed that part? I think I was focused on Lambie's comment.

Comment: @dubious, the difference is that your answer offers three possibilities and leaves it open how they are related to each other.

Answer (score 3):

"restauración" means:

**the restaurant business or industry**

From the Real Academia dictionary (the OED of Spanish)
restauración:
Actividad de quien tiene o explota un restaurante.
*The activity of a person who has or runs a restaurant*.

From a trade publication called:
Restaurant Business

> How do we judge 2023? In some respects, this was the first “normal”
> year the **restaurant industry** had since 2019. And yet everything seemed
> so not normal.
>
> We spent most of the year worried about the economy. And yet by
> December, the U.S. consumer continued to spend, even if they did so a
> bit less often to adjust to prices. Restaurant companies boasted about
> performance and upped their projections for new unit growth.
> AND
> Here come the robots
> In 10 years, we might look back on 2023 and think this was really the year’s biggest story. Well, that or tipping. But robots are coming for the **restaurant business**, whether you like it or not.

[Restaurant Business online](https://www.restaurantbusinessonline.com/financing/biggest-restaurant-stories-2023)

Reference: Personal knowledge re Spanish-to-English translation

**EDIT** due to responses

food and beverage industry in **Spanish** is:
industria de alimentación y bebidas OR alimentos y bebidas.

And hospitality industry in **Spanish** is:
industria de hospitalidad

From a Spanish site in Spain:

> [...] Entonces,  lo que es la hospitalidad en el turismo se puede
> desarrollar en sus distintas áreas como: la recreación,
> entretenimiento, hotelería, hospedaje o alojamiento, actividades
> culturales,  excursiones, exposiciones, celebraciones, transporte,
> administración de la industria hotelera,  gastronomía, entre otras.
> [Que es hospitalidad en el turismo?](https://www.euroinnova.edu.es/blog/que-es-la-hospitalidad-en-el-turismo)
> [translations]  So, hospitality in the
> tourism industry can be broken down into its various areas such as
> recreation, entertainment, the hotel industry, cultural activities, tourist excursions, hosting & lodging, exhibitions,
> events (celebrations), transportation, hotel management, and cookery (cusine),
> among others.

Comment: This only covers eateries, not as the question asked "restaurants, bars, cafeterias, taverns, etc".

Comment: @terdon No, the OP's question is slightly off but the word **in Spanish and Portuguese and French means** the food business or industry. 5. f. Real Academia dictionary: Actividad de quien tiene o explota un restaurante. The activity of a person who has or runs a restaurant. //Whoever downvoted is mistaken and does not know Spanish.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I am well aware of the meaning of the word. However, the question explicitly mentions "bars, cafeterias", which are not covered by _restauración_ in Spanish nor "the restaurant business" in English.

Comment: @terdon So. the OP is mistaken. And I provided the right translation for restauración. But nothing about my answer merits a downvote. His explanation is wrong re the meaning **in English** of restauración.

Comment: @jsw29 It's in my quote from that trade magazine. The restaurant business or industry is made up of restaurant companies ranging from mom-and-pop foodstands to fancy, 4 Michelin star establishments.

Answer (score 2):

The Wiktionary entry for the Spanish word "[restauración](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/restauraci%C3%B3n)" gives the English translation as "[restaurateurship](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/restaurateurship#English)":

> The fact of being a restaurateur; ownership and management of a restaurant.

Looking up [other translations](https://context.reverso.net/translation/spanish-english/Restauraci%C3%B3n) suggests "[catering](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/catering#English)"

> The business of providing food and related services; foodservice.

The above mentions "[foodservice](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/foodservice#English)":

> The business of providing food and related services.

Comment: That wiktionary translation is wrong. I should go there and change it as anyone could.

Comment: @Lambie Your attitude on this question has been very coarse and out of proportion

Comment: A very coarse attitude? Hmm. Generally, people are coarse. I believe I was just making a cogent argument which may be perceived as harshly delivered. But in fact, I have shown quite a lot of patience and forbearance.

Comment: I'll try not to be as harsh, but I agree with Lambie. "catering" refers to providing food for events, parties, etc. It doesn't usually include establishments that serve individual customers, provide takeout.

Comment: I just noticed that Wikipedia says that in British English "catering" is equivalent to US "foodservice". I don't know BrE well enough to dispute that.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to suggest <strike>*gastronomy industry*</strike>, but after some research would actually advise against it. Some background:

In German we have *Gastronomie* for the sector of the economy that commercially serves food and drinks to other people. This would include bars and restaurants in hotels but not the rest of their business.

The English cognate [**gastronomy**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gastronomy) has a somewhat different focus: The "art, science, customs or style" of preparing and eating good food.

When googling "<strike>gastronomy industry</strike>" a number of usages turn up, among them ["Addressing COVID-19 in the gastronomy industry"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0278431921000396), labor statistics and trade fair announcements. It all looks legit; but then I see the [a page from the *Bundesagentur für Arbeit*](https://www.arbeitsagentur.de/vor-ort/zav/projects-programs/hospitality/hotel-gastronomy) who want to lure foreigners into low-payed jobs that no German wants to do. They say "working in the hotel and gastronomy industry", which raises a red flag: It is a direct translation of the technical German term [*Hotel- und Gaststättengewerbe*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gastgewerbe) which is the German equivalent of "hospitality industry".

When I check the other google hits, the trade fair is in Germany, the article is by a Southern Tyrolean, Dutch and Chinese group, the statistics are from Dubai and the German Fraunhofer society has written something as well.

**Very few, if any, hits are by native English speakers.** In a way, this resembles the [recursive AI training data poisoning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2305.17493.pdf) which happens if AI generated content is fed back into the training data. Germans take mistakes made by other Germans at face value and perpetuate them until they become part of the unwieldy, un-beautiful, hard-to-read "English as a utility language".

Comment: So your answer is "not this term"? :)

Comment: @Joachim The evolution of this technical answer is: I started writing "why not gastronomy", thought it wise to look it up first and found the presumed meaning actually not listed. Oops. Started googling, found many hits, continued with the article. Took a closer look at the links. Oops. Rewrote the article, adding a few "nots" and "`<strike>s". I think it is valuable for all the German, Dutch, Dubaian and Chinese non-native authors of technical and PR texts: We should our research not only when it yielded the desired results, now, should we!? ;-)

Comment: That's understandable, and thorough, and transparent :) So it's more like "in case this is to be considered a proper synonymous term—it is not". I'm wondering how this information can still be put to use. Could it be turned into a self-answered question, or a question asking for the cause of the diverging definitions?

Comment: While this is not, strictly speaking, an answer to the question, it is a valuable contribution to this page. The term may seem tempting to some people, and as the answer explains, it does have some limited currency, so it is worthwhile to have here a well developed (longer than would fit a comment) explanation of its origin.